# Which are necessary steps to connect to an Azure SQL database in Visual Studio or SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with update 5. I created a SQL database on Azure.

Now I am trying to connect to it in VS and SQL Server Management Studio, but I get this error

> Error : Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to MyServerName.database.windows.net.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
>
> The network path was not found

Before connecting to Azure SQL I have taken these steps:

- Added machine's IP in SQL Azure firewall
- Opened port 1433 by adding a new outbound rule in firewall on my local machine

I want know which step I missing in whole process.

Comment: Did you try to turn off the firewall on your machine? (just to be sure)

Comment: look at this: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/, make sure the connection string is in the correct format.

Comment: maybe you can try to use another machine to make sure that's it's not computer configuration related issue.

Comment: check this and follow the steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956465/use-sql-server-management-studio-to-connect-remotely-to-an-sql-server-express-in

Comment: Connectionstring is correct and also tried on another machine, but it giving same error.

Comment: its probably a bad setting in your connection string, here i posted how to extract every needed values for the connection string for MSSQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770652/symfony-connect-with-windows-azure/34772811

Answer (score 1):

Well. This is hapenning because tha address you're using isn't ok to access. Try to connect through the IP, and make sure you're using the PUBLIC IP/DNS. Try to open the firewall on both sides. That's all that I could help you with the information error reported for you. The conection string that you're using is not ok or not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

VS2013 and above has a decent cloud explorer screen, I'd recommend navigating to the resource through that first.  You can also use the Server Explorer to navigate to the right resource and open in in SQL Server Object Explorer.  That will at least eliminate if it's an issue with your stored credentials.