# Diagnosing Error when connecting Sql Server Management to Azure - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: sql-server, azure

I created a basic tier Sql Database in Azure. I would like to connect to it in SSMS. I am getting an error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused

I have seen several questions on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809405/which-are-necessary-steps-to-connect-to-an-azure-sql-database-in-visual-studio-o) , which lead me to believe the issue is a firewall issue. How can I confirm this? I get the same error when entering an incorrect password. Is there an uncomplicated work-around if I am on a work network, and cant make any major firewall configuration changes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would seem related to the firewall. If you are on the work network your workplace IP should be whitelisted. If it's not, there is a tab for the network settings in Azure if you go to your SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen several questions on Stackoverflow , which lead me to
>   believe the issue is a firewall issue. How can I confirm this?

For the network-related error, you could confirm it via using [telnet](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/articles/telnet/) tool in CMD or [Test-NetConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps) commands in Powershell. For example, to verify a TCP connection to your SQL database server on port 1433, issue the command on your local machine:

```
telnet yoursqlserver.database.windows.net 1433
```

If the connection succeeds, a blank screen will show up, meaning that the computer port is open.

A failed connection will be accompanied by an error message. It can indicate either a closed port or the fact that the indicated remote server is not listening on the provided port.

For more information, Here is a guide to [troubleshoot the database firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#troubleshoot-the-database-firewall).